# Reopen ActiveRecord class from an initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to add an association to my `Comment` class from a different location than `comment.rb`, e.g. in an initializer. Something like:

```
# in config/initializers/comment_setup.rb
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :replies
end
```

But when I try this (rails 2.3.4) I get an error that the has_many association does not exist.

What's the best way to re-open an ActiveRecord class from a location other than `app/models/blah.rb`?

Comment: I'm adding a similar association to several models and I'd like to do it all in one file for maintenance purposes

Answer (score 0):

Having seen your comment, I think you're going about this the wrong way. Take a look at polymorphic associations, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

It's a way to have one model be associated to many models by storing the type (i.e. the class name of the model) of the association, as well as the ID. This is how you reuse an association across several models.